# Greasemonkey 4.x: working with multiple .js files

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4

I'm working on a user script that's growing in size and getting a little bit hard to manage, so I was thinking of moving some functionality to a separate *.js* file (or files). AFAIK, (since GM 4.0) you can't really access your script's location on disk since it's not stored as such, so there's not a directory in which you could put additional *.js* files you might want to use (and then load them with *@require* or *@resource*). This also extends to *.css* files. Is this correct? GM's wiki seems to be either outdated or incomplete.

Is there a workaround for this? I'm fairly new to the user script arena, but I feel like this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: This is one of the many things busted by GM4 and Firefox "Quantum".  Some have reported success with *Tampermonkey* and `@require`ing local files.  But I've yet to find a decent workaround for developing scripts since Firefox went fubar.

Comment: Nearly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509874/how-to-update-tampermonkey-script-to-a-local-file-programatically