# Can synchronised browser testing be achieved when the user script (Tampermonkey) is developed locally?

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

I am developing a user script (Tampermonkey) locally. When the local JS changes, I want to automatically refresh the target URL of the user script instead of a local HTML file.

How can this be achieved?  I checked every command and configuration information, but did not find a solution, so I came to ask for help.

[The method of developing UserScript locally is seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55568568/11901563). The answerer mentioned that browser-sync can be used, but I did not find a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

livereload can solve this problem very well, because livereload is implemented through browser extensions and local programs. When the file changes, the target URL can be refreshed immediately.

http://livereload.com/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei/related